# How to trigger datastore update if condition is met? (Google App Engine - Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datastore

In my application I have a column `display` with values `y` or `n`. Default value is `n` and the item is not displayed. When payment is received the value is changed to `y` and the item is displayed. If the item is not renewed in a month I would like to change it to `n`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tricky part if calculating the dates; I assume that you know how to change the value itself.

You'll need to store the date of renewal, and check them periodically using [Scheduled Tasks With Cron for Python](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html) or [Java](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron.html).

Just create a job that changes all expired accounts to `n` after a certain time period (here, 1 month), and have it run every day, or every hour.

Answer (score 4):

Schedule a cron job to periodically check and update your data. See http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html